# How do I display the Indian regional languages properly in Android tablet?

Tags: android, unicode, localization, typeface

I need to display Telugu text in an Android application. I am able to display in Android mobiles using ttf font files. But I am not able to display properly in tablets and the emulator. I do not care about the emulator. But I want to display properly in tablets, so please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

My sample code for displaying Telugu text in the mobile is

```
final Typeface telugu = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");
yourName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameofyours12);
yourName.setTypeface(telugu);
```